# How to set Enter in to massage that sent via Requests in to Telegram Channel

Tags: python, request, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I sending post to teleram Channel via Requests lib and i need to add Enter for better formate in channel and i use `\n` at the end of lines but it dosen't work is there any idea for this

This is my code

```
import requests

def Telegram_channel (x):
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendMessage"
    data = {"chat_id":"-USER_id", "text":x}
    r = requests.post(url, json=data)


x = ">>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database : \n"

x = x,">>>> Torrent Link DB value ",torrent_link,'\n'

Telegram_channel (x)
```

and the result is :

```
>>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database  \n>>>> Torrent Link DB value \n
```

but it should be like this

```
>>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database 

>>>> Torrent Link DB value
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually creating a `tuple` instead of `str` (which `text` JSON parameter should be):

```py
x = ">>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database : \n"
x = x,">>>> Torrent Link DB value ","torrent_link_text_here",'\n'
print(type(x))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
('>>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database : \n', '>>>> Torrent Link DB value ', 'torrent_link_text_here', '\n')
```

Requests lib cannot treat it correctly to construct an HTTP request, so you lose line breaks.

---

Why not use [string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)?

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage"
torrent_link = "https://example.com"
x = ">>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database: \n>>>> Torrent Link DB value {}\n".format(torrent_link)

data = {"chat_id": <YOUR_CHAT_ID>, "text": x}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Chat output:

```
>>>> length of Tv packs banned in Database:  
>>>> Torrent Link DB value https://example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below :

**Basically the parameter you need to send in this api, in query params**, and actually you are sending them in body, so please send in query string and enjoy coding.

**URL :** 
https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_API_KEY]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MY_CHANNEL_NAME]&text=[MY_MESSAGE_TEXT]

**METHOD : GET**
where:

- **BOT_API_KEY** is the API Key generated by BotFather when you created
  your bot
- **MY_CHANNEL_NAME** is the handle of your channel (e.g.
  @my_channel_name)
- **MY_MESSAGE_TEXT** is the message you want to send
  (URL-encoded)